# How to import a function when the namespace is used?

Tags: python-2.7, import, namespaces

I am trying to import a function. The namespace of the folder/files are taken up by files in the working directory. I am trying to find a way where I can import this:

- without changing any names
- only importing the function into the working file

(`package_1` and `package_2` below are the source folders)

```
package_1\
    foo\
        __init__.py
        bar.py (myfunc, myfunc2 in this file)

package_2\
    subpackage_2\
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
        hoo.py
```

I want `myfunc` and `myfunc2` to be imported into `hoo.py`
What I would usually do:

```
from foo.bar import myfunc, myfunc2
```

however `foo` is already taken (also `bar`but I don't think that matters too much)

### Solution I have tried:

I can get this to work by importing into the `__init__.py` of `subpackage_2` and then importing again:

`__init__.py`:

```
from foo.bar import myfunc, myfunc2
```

`hoo.py`:

```
from subpackage_2 import myfunc, myfunc2
```

However I don't want to import into the whole sub-package

### Tried but not succeeded:

I have been playing around with trying to temporarily remove `package_2` from the `sys.path` and then import, then adding `package_2` back in. I can't really find the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer (or at least it works). Although if there is a better one I would love to know.

```
bar = __import__('foo.bar') # I did initially use from_list but looks like I don't need it
myfunc, myfunc2 = bar.myfunc, bar.myfunc2
```